# Chose 3 numbers with maximum LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Given $N$, find 3 numbers $x,y,z \le N$ such that their LCM is maximised.

Eg: for $N=5$, ans is $60$ as it is the highest lcm achieved by combination $3,4,5$.

Comment: When $N$ is even the answer will be the maximum between $(N, N-1, N-3)$ and $(N-1, N-2, N-3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For odd $N\ge 3$, the choice $$(N-2,N-1,N)$$ is optimal because the three entries are pairwise coprime

For even $N\ge 4$, the choice $$(N-3,N-2,N-1)$$ is optimal if $N$ is divisble by $3$, otherwise the choice $$(N-3,N-1,N)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{lcm}(a, b, c) = \frac{abc}{\gcd(ab,ac,bc)}$$

This quantity is maximized when the numerator is large and the denominator is small. The denominator is minimized if all three quantities are coprime, so the goal is pick the largest three coprime numbers $\leq N$.

For odd $N$: Choose $(N, N-1, N-2)$

For even $N$: Choose $(N, N-1, N-3)$ unless $N$ is divisible by $3$, in which case choose $(N-1, N-2, N-3)$